# Decrypting password correctly after EncryptByPassPhrase

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I am trying to Encrypt and then Decrypt text in SQL Server 2012. I was expecting the third print to give me back `customer_abc`:

```
DECLARE 
@var_customer VARCHAR(25),
@var_password VARBINARY(8000)

SET @var_customer = 'customer_abc'

SET @var_password = EncryptByPassPhrase('secret', @var_customer )

print @var_customer
print @var_password
print DecryptByPassPhrase('secret', @var_password )
```

Result:

> customer_abc
>   
> 0x01000000398F9A0D3FE98D29E8F56D6B1908EA87C08706786319DD1BBB3F150FFC5B7F3C
>   
> 0x637573746F6D65725F616263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that you have to explicitly convert to get the actual varchar value. The output of `Decrypt` functions are still in binary. Change the last line to:

```
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DecryptByPassPhrase('secret', @var_password));
```

As an aside, I strongly suggest you support Unicode (so `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`). Unless you want to look like you don't take your users' password security seriously.